# SQL syntax error '' near line way outside my file length

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I have this code to send the data of 3 input fields for an id-number and 2 dates (2 selectors, one text field) to my database. All 3 columns are VARCHAR. I am using a form with method POST.

I get this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 336

I do not have 336 lines in any of my files.

This is what PHP and SQL code I have in my file. I've been going through it for a long while now but can't seem to find where this syntax error lies. Any ideas?

```
<?php
//Fetches the id of the konsert selected.
$id = $_GET['id'];

//Create DB object
$db = new Database();

//Create query to fetch personel
$query = "SELECT * FROM funktionar";

//Run above query
$personel = $db->select($query);

//Fetch all from konsert matching the id
$query = "SELECT * FROM konsert WHERE konsertID=".$id;

//Run above query
$konsert = $db->select($query);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //Assign variables
    $namn = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['personalID']);
    $tidStart = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['tidStart']);
    $tidSlut = mysqli_real_escape_string($db->link, $_POST['tidSlut']);

    //Simple validation
    if($namn == '' || $tidStart == '' || $tidSlut == ''){
        //Set error if any field is left empty
        $error = 'V&auml;nligen fyll i alla f&auml;lt.';
        } else {
        $query = "INSERT INTO sakerhet
            (personalID, tidStart, tidSlut)
            VALUES ('$namn', '$tidStart', '$tidSlut')";

        $insert_row = $db->insert($query);
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT:**
Have added the insert function:

```
public function insert($query) {
       $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

       //Validate insert
       if($insert_row) {
           header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
           exit();
       } else {
           die('Error : ('.$this->link->errno .') '.$this->link->error);
       }

   }
```

Comment: Do you have any log to see what is arriving to your server? Plus are you using MySQL or SQL-Server? Remove the tags of products you don't use.

Comment: @Cynical the OP use MariaDB  .. is the same of mysql ..

Comment: Could you try `$query = "SELECT * FROM konsert WHERE konsertID=$id";`

Comment: It's not complaining about a line in any of your files, it's complaining about a line in your SQL query

Comment: Be careful! `$id` is subject to [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Could you please show what `$db->insert($query)` exactly  does? I find it bewildering that the error message talks about "line 336" of the SQL statement... No statement is even nearly that long here...

Comment: @EagleRainbow Curious, in what way is $id a risk? Good to know. And I'll add the insert function to the post.

Comment: @Cynical I use XAMPP, phpmyadmin, etc, and no I don't seem to have a log file for it.

Comment: @Arulkumar I've tried that, it returns nothing from the table.

Comment: Depending on how `$db->query` has been implemented, I would try to send along the value `"4711; TRUNCATE TABLE sakerhet;"`. Your query `$query = "SELECT * FROM konsert WHERE konsertID=".$id;` then suddenly would end up with `$query = "SELECT * FROM konsert WHERE konsertID=4711; TRUNCATE TABLE sakerhet;"`, which in fact consists of two queries - one, which returns what you want, and the other, which will cause you to lose all your data, as `mysql_query()` (for instance) just will execute both commands sequentially. You wouldn't be the first one getting hacked this way...

Comment: What is `$this->link` referring to? An instance of `mysqli`?

Comment: given that `$insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);`, I would assume that `336` simply is a concatenation of "line 3" (with which the error message ends) and the line of the current line where the error message is raised, i.e `36` -- there's no separator in the `die()` command... doah!

Comment: Just for the sake of error analysis, could you just add a "var_dump($query)" right in front of `$insert_row = $db->insert($query);` and post what's in there?

Comment: @EagleRainbow Ty, I'll have to look deeper into how to prevent such hacking. As for now, the insert function lies on rows 47-59 in a separate file, while the query sent to it lies on, indeed, row 36 in its file. I think that adding "var_dump($query)" resulting in nothing confirms the error lies before the query is even sent to the function?

Comment: The idea behind `var_dump($query)` is to verbatimly get, what is sent to the DB. Apparently, the DB doesn't like what we are sending. Given all the escape issues, I think it's good practice to see 1:1 what is getting sent to the DB. Perhaps this gives us the pivotal hint we all are looking for so desperately...

Comment: @EagleRainbow The DB is sent an person's ID number and two dates of the format "XXXX-XX-XX HH:MM". Does VARCHAR handle spaces between characters...? MAybe a stupid question but I'm grasping at anything here at this hour.

Comment: So, you get something like `INSERT INTO sakerhet (personalID, tidStart, tidSlut) VALUES ('4711', '2016-05-29 23:11', '2016-05-29 23:12')`, right? If `tidStart` and `tidSlut` are both typed `VARCHAR`, then the space inbetween there should not pose any problem at all...

Comment: What happens, if you verbatimely copy&paste that `INSERT` statement, which you just got and paste it in phpMyAdmin? Does the same error message get raised there as well?

Comment: @EagleRainbow Thank you, by narrowing it down like this I've lastly found that the 'personalID' column and its relation to a column 'namn' is not at all fetched from the database the way it should be from start and thus my code tries to send it to nothing. I need to join another column from another table.

Comment: Appreciating that we finally were able to catch that bug - so in short this means that MySQL wanted us to say that a column (or a value?) was not there? What a bad error message in that case!

Comment: @EagleRainbow A bad and very vague one indeed, I'd not call that a syntax error. That's a missing value or missing column. Pretty much sent me staring at the wrong thing for hours. Thank you for your help, I'll be adding what solved it once able.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final and working solution. This SQL error occured due to:

- Missing table column. While the error was too vague to give this direct answer I put all input data into simple variables instead á "$selected = $_POST['name']" and echoed the variables á "echo $konsert;", etc, to check so the data was fetched properly from its form. Commenting out the query as I did.
- Likely wrong use of either mysqli_real_escape_string or "->link->"? I do not work in sessions with this project as it's not required and won't go public so removing this will be alright for me.

**Conclusion**
It wasn't as much a syntax error as the query having problems executing itself due to above. The syntax was correct.

**Disclaimer**
This code is not 100% safe nor 100% done. The input fields are NOT sanitised and as was pointed out to me by @EagleRainbow it is not safe to use the "$id = $_GET['id'];".

**Code**

```
<?php
//Fetches the id of the konsert selected.
$id = $_GET['id'];

//Create DB object
$db = new Database();

//Create query to fetch personel
$query = "SELECT * FROM funktionar";

//Run above query
$personel = $db->select($query);

//Select all from table sakerhet
$query = "SELECT * FROM sakerhet";

//Run above query
$safety = $db->select($query);

//Fetch all from konsert matching the id
$query = "SELECT * FROM konsert WHERE konsertID=".$id;

//Run above query
$konsert = $db->select($query);

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        //Assign variables
        $selected = $_POST['safetyName'];
        $tidStart = $_POST['tidStart'];
        $tidSlut = $_POST['tidSlut'];
        $konsert = $id;

        //Simple validation
        if($selected == '' || $tidStart == '' || $tidSlut == ''){
            //Set error if any field is left empty
            $error = "V&auml;nligen fyll i alla f&auml;lt.";
            } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO sakerhet (personalID, tidStart, tidSlut, konsertID) VALUES ('$selected', '$tidStart', '$tidSlut', '$konsert')";
                $insert_row = $db->insert($query);
        }
    }
?>
```

**Code from database file**

```
public function insert($query) {
       $insert_row = $this->link->query($query) or die($this->link->error.__LINE__);

       //Validate insert
       if($insert_row) {
           header("Location: index.php?msg=".urlencode('Record Added'));
           exit();
       } else {
           die('Error : ('.$this->link->errno .') '.$this->link->error);
       }

   }
```

Thanks for the help given.